# how to loop around around a specific button in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

i have this forloop that creates buttons in a grid layout with a 2d array

```
public Board(){
  gameBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,8));
  array = new JButton[8][8];

  int limit = 8;
  for(int i = 0; i< limit; i++){
      for(int t = 0; t< limit; t++){
       JButton button = new JButton("");
       gameBoard.add(button);
       array[i][t] = button;   
       array[i][t].addActionListener(e -> newMethod(e));
    }
  }
```

i also have this method that should idealy loop around a button when its clicked and change the surrounding buttons depending on the conditions but i do not know how to loop around the specific button that gets clicked. any tips on how to do this

```
 public void newMethod(ActionEvent e){
   JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
    gameLogic(b);
    BPlayer = !BPlayer;
    System.out.println(BPlayer); 
    System.out.println(b);
```

}

```
 public void gameLogic(JButton b){
 int limit = 8;
 // Black Players Turn
 if(BPlayer && b.getText().equals("") ){
  b.setText("B");
      for(int i = 0; i< limit; i++){
      for(int t = 0; t< limit; t++){
       if(array[i][t].getText().equals("W")){
          b.setText("B");
         }
            else if(array[i][t].getText().equals("B")){
             //do nothing 
            }
            else if(array[i][t].getText().equals("")){
                // do nothing like everything else 
            }

    }
  }     
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  I don't see anything you've tried to "loop around" the pressed button.

Answer (score 0):

To loop around a button, you need to be able to figure out where that button is on your game board.  One way would be to store the button's coordinate in the button:

```
private final static String POS_KEY = "btnPosKey";

Board() {
    ...
        button.putClientProperty(POS_KEY, new int[]{i, t});
    ...
}
```

Your game logic may then retrieve the coordinate of the button the was clicked from the button itself:

```
void gameLogic(JButton b) {
    int[] pos = (int[]) b.getClientProperty(POS_KEY);
    int i = pos[0], t = pos[1];
```

Looping around the button is as simple as iterating over the small 3x3 square, centered on the (i,t) coordinate.

```
    for(int di = i - 1;  di <= i + 1;  di++) {
        for (int dt = t - 1; dt <= t + 1;  dt++) {
```

But you don't want to go outside the bounds of your game grid ...

```
            if ( di >= 0  &&  di < limit   &&   dt >= 0  &&  dt < limit ) {
```

Or possibly include you center button ...

```
                if (di != i  || dt != t) {
                    array[di][dt].setText("B");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Of course, there are other ways to determine the coordinate of the button, instead of storing it using `putClientProperty()`:

- derive your own class from `JButton`, and store the coordinates as fields.
- pass the `i` and `t` coordinates in the `e -> newMethod(e, fi, ft)` lambda, using `fi` and `ft` as local `final` copies of the `i` and `t` variables.
- searching for the button in the `array` of buttons to determine the coordinates.

Use whatever method is most convenient for you.